# How do I make a git patch from multiple commits at different points in history?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-patch

I am trying to create a git patch from multiple commits in my branch. However, I need to create it from arbitrary commits (they wont necessarily be in a range). In between the commits I want to create a patch out of, some of the commits change some of the files in the patch may have also been changed.

Here is my use case (assume greater number = later commit date):

```
develop HEAD
Commit 5 - Changed a.txt
Commit 4 - Changed a.txt, b.txt, c.txt
Commit 3 - Changed b.txt, c.txt
Commit 2 - Changed a.txt
Commit 1 - Changed a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, d.txt
master HEAD
```

Now I want to be able to create a patch for commits 1, 3 and 5 from the develop branch and apply them to the master branch.

I've looked around and all I can find is the ability to create a patch in a range. Is there a way to create a patch for multiple commits with potential changes in the files between them?

Comment: Have you tried cherry-pick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a new branch from HEAD in `master`

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b newBranch
```

Cherry Pick the commits here.

```
git cherry-pick commit1SHA
git cherry-pick commit3SHA
git cherry-pick commit5SHA
```

Create a patch from this.

```
git format-patch master --stdout > nameOfPatch.patch
```

Now, you want to move commits 1,3,5 from develop to master. You can simply do this by following the above statements till the last cherry-pick and then :

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Now, pick the first commit and squash the other two. You now have one solitary commit that encapsulates all three of the other commits. Now, just cherry-pick this commmit, say `squashedCommitSHA` to master.

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick squashedCommitSHA
```

Comment: The last line writes output in mbox format to a file named `.patch`, which is confusing.

Comment: Moreover, my understanding of the OP's problem is that they might want to cherry-pick into master directly, and only asked about creating a "patch" due to the assumption that this might be necessary to get selected commits into master.

Comment: Oh I just got that. Thanks!

Comment: Updated with a way to just move the stuff around to master.

Comment: This is really easy to do with `gitk`.  Just check out the branch you want to modify, then right click -> cherry pick on each commit you want.  (In the order you want them, of course.)